# How do I remove a user by key or value?

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

I have a structure in my Firebase database like this:

```
--users
    --v7BwBnUBqJMXCtoOHYE51jXCwhY2: uid
    --etc
```

The users 'table' gets populated when a user gets authenticated like this:

```
  loginFb() {
    this.af.auth.login({
      provider: AuthProviders.Facebook,
      method: AuthMethods.Popup,
    }).then(
        (user) => {
        this.userOnline(user.uid, 'uid');
        this.router.navigate(['/members']);
      }).catch(
        (err) => {
        this.error = err;
      })
  }

  userOnline(uid, value) {
    const users = this.af.database.object('/users');
    users.update({ [uid]: value });
  }
```

This gives ea user a uid in the user table thats generated by fb.

I want to remove the user when they logout. Researching this I have come across this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42275384/how-to-angularfire2-remove-by-some-key-value).

I applied it as such:

```
  logout(userUID) {
    this.af.auth.logout();
    this.userOffline(userUID);
    this.router.navigateByUrl('/login');
  }

  userOffline(userUID) {

    const user = this.af.database.list('/', {
      query: {
        orderByChild: userUID,
        equalTo: 'uid'
      }
    });

    user.subscribe(snapshots=>{
      snapshots.forEach(snapshot => {
        console.log(snapshot);
        snapshot.ref.remove();
      });
    })

  }
```

The result of the console.log is:

```
Object {v7BwBnUBqJMXCtoOHYE51jXCwhY2: "uid", $key: "users"}
```

Alas I get this error:

```
Cannot read property 'remove' of undefined
```

I'm sure there is a better way to do this but I couldn't find anything. Any advice is appreciated.

**EDIT**

Thanks to @pengyy comment I made a minor amend to their suggestion.

```
user.subscribe(snapshots=>{
  snapshots.forEach(snapshot => {
    console.log(snapshot);
    this.af.database.list('/users').remove(snapshot.userUID)
  });
})
```

This works and removes the user but it does so straight away on page load not even when the function is called... the plot thickens

Comment: why would you constantly write to table and delete everytime user logins ? if this data is going to get deleted anyways isnt it better to leave in angular ?

Comment: I want to know who is logged in / online at any time

Comment: Although @EduardoDennis would it be better to have a list of users and have a 'online status' change on login and out? I think this makes sense as I also want to persist the groups the users belong to. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  userOffline(userUID) {
    this.af.database.list('/users/'+userUID).remove();
  }
```

So this works. So simple...

Thanks @pengyy I wouldn't have got there without your comments.

Comment: I ended up using this method:
---
`logout(userUID) {
    this.af.auth.logout();
    this.userOffline(userUID);
    this.router.navigateByUrl('/login');
  }`
---
  `userOffline(userUID) {
    const user = this.af.database.list('/users');
    user.update(userUID, { userOnline: false });
  }`
---
As this will persist the user data. Use update not push so not to remove existing data. Refer the [docs](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/3-retrieving-data-as-lists.md)

Answer (score 2):

remove item from table by

```
this.af.database.list('/users').remove(snapshot.$key)
```

Comment: User is still there I'm afraid.
snapshot.$key returns just 'user' so it won't work.

Comment: sorry, first of all, you should query the exact table "users" for the $key. After you edited, you mean that the users is deleted before the function is called?

Comment: It is necessary to tag anyone but the author of the post (question or answer) that you're replying to. Smiter probably never saw you answer. You tag people by typing @ and the first letter, an auto-complete list will be presented. I didn't need to tag you because you're the author I'm replying to. **Also** Perhaps you can edit your answer and elaborate to help this person and others more.